# Swift open twitter profile with action button

Tags: swift, twitter

I'm trying to open my Twitter profile with clicking the button and when I click the button its opening with Safari, but I want to open with twitter app how can I do this and what I did wrong on here ?

```
let twUrl = URL(string: "twitter://user?screen_name=wixvii")!
let twUrlWeb = URL(string: "https://www.twitter.com/wixvii")!
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(twUrl){
   UIApplication.shared.open(twUrl, options: [:],completionHandler: nil) 
}else{
   UIApplication.shared.open(twUrlWeb, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this command in to info.plist you can solve this problem.

> LSApplicationQueriesSchemes
>
> twitter

Answer (score 1):

**1. Add to Info.plist source code in Xcode or TextEdit next strings:**

> ```
> <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
> <array>
> <string>twitter</string>
> </array>
> ```

[image]

**2. Use this function to open Twitter in your iOS app:**

```
func twitter() {
 
   let lowerCaseSocialNetworkName = "twitter"
   let socialNetworkDomain = "com"
   let userName = "bandyliuk"
   let appURL = URL(string: "\(lowerCaseSocialNetworkName)://user? screen_name=\(userName)")!
   let application = UIApplication.shared
 
   if application.canOpenURL(appURL) {
      application.open(appURL)
   } else {
      let webURL = URL(string: "https://\(lowerCaseSocialNetworkName).\ (socialNetworkDomain)/\(userName)")!
   application.open(webURL)
   }
 
}
```